# Angular 5 Datepicker - Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I am trying to keep the Angular Material Datepicker open by default on rendering of the page inside a section so it's not like an input field and doesn't require the user to click on an input to see the calendar.

This is the one I'm using and it requires clicking on the input field at the moment. https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**MatDatepicker** has an `open()` method  and a `toggle` property.
Either call `open()` on `ngOnInit()` or set `toggle: enable` .
Though I'm not sure that toggle will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**MatDatePicker** has some properties defined, You can use @Input(opened) for this.
Sample code for your reference

```
`<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker #picker opened=true></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>`
```